# Circular linked list C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, queue

I'm trying to create a queue using a circular linked list. I just took my existing linked list implementation (which already works) and changed where the nodes pointed but it doesn't seem to be that straightforward. I'm sure it's one small thing that I'm overlooking.

```
void enqueue(int q){
    newNode=new node;
    newNode->info = q;
    newNode->link = first;

    if(first->link==first){
        first = last = newNode;
        last->link=first;
    }

    else{
       last->link = newNode;
       last= newNode;
       last->link = first;
    }           
}

int dequeue(){
    int x;
    if(first->link==first){
        cout <<"The Queue is empty" <<endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        dummy=first;
        x=dummy->info;
        first=first->link;
        delete(dummy);
        return(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't paste code without actually saying what's wrong.

Comment: Draw nodes on paper. Draw existing connections between nodes. One by one change the connections until the desired node configuration is reached. Implement in code. If it still doesn't doesn't work, five bucks says spotting the problem is trivial if you step through the code with a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I converted this to a class. For a circular list class, only a pointer to last node is needed, as first = last->next. Since no dummy node is used, an empty list is normally indicated by last == NULL;

```
#include<iostream>

class circq
{
    typedef struct node_
    {
        struct node_ *next;
        int info;
    }node;

    node *last;                         // ptr to last node of list

public:

    circq()                             // constructor
    {
        last = NULL;                    // reset last
    }

    bool isempty()
    {
        return last == NULL;
    }

    void enqueue(int q)
    {
        node *newNode=new node;         // new node
        newNode->info = q;
        if(last == NULL){               // if empty list
            last = newNode;             //  create single node list
            newNode->next = newNode;
            return;
        }                               // else
        newNode->next = last->next;     //  append node to end list
        last->next = newNode;
        last = newNode;
    }

    int dequeue()
    {
        if(last == NULL){               // check for empty list
            return 0;
        }
        node *first = last->next;       // set ptr to first node
        int x = first->info;            // set return value
        if(last->next == last)          // if single node
            last = NULL;                //  set list to empty
        else                            // else
            last->next = first->next;   //  advance first to next node
        delete first;                   // delete node
        return x;
    }

    ~circq()                            // destructor
    {
        while(!isempty())
            dequeue();
    }
};

int main()                              // test circq
{
circq cq;
    cq.enqueue(0);
    cq.enqueue(1);
    cq.enqueue(2);
    cq.enqueue(3);
    while(!cq.isempty())
        std::cout << cq.dequeue() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```